# ActivityResultLauncher not re-registered after Fragment recreated

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have a fragment where I am using DefaultLifecycleObserver to handle launching a file chooser and getting content (via a uri).  The first time my fragment is created in the activity lifecycle, the behavior works fine.  If I navigate to a different fragment and come back, the fragment gets recreated, but the ActivityResultLauncher is not re-registered.

I was able to get around the issue by creating a `cleanup()` function that manually unregisters the Activity result launcher.  I call this cleanup method in the Fragment's `onDestroy()` and it fixes the issue.  However, this approach feels very hacky.  What is the idiomatic way of handling re-registering the ActivityResultLauncher?

```kotlin
class FileSelectorLifecycleObserver(private val registry : ActivityResultRegistry, private val callback: (Uri) -> Unit):
    DefaultLifecycleObserver {
    private lateinit var getContent: ActivityResultLauncher<String>

    override fun onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        getContent = registry.register("com.histogramo.app.FILE_LOAD", owner, ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri ->
            uri?.let { callback(it) }
        }
    }

    fun cleanup() { getContent.unregister() }

    fun selectFile() { getContent.launch("application/octet-stream")  }
}

class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: MyFragmentBinding? = null
    private val binding
        get() = _binding

    private lateinit var observer : FileSelectorLifecycleObserver

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        _binding = null
        super.onDestroyView()
        observer.cleanup()
        lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = MyFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        observer = FileSelectorLifecycleObserver(requireActivity().activityResultRegistry) { uri ->
            // DO STUFF WITH THE FILE
        }
        lifecycle.addObserver(observer)
        return binding?.root ?: View(context)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding?.loadFileButton?.setOnClickListener {
            activity?.let { observer.selectFile() }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's just a guess maybe it is due to registering the file picker in the observer. if you do it in Fragment's ```onCreate()``` method you'll not get any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using

```
lifecycle.addObserver(observer)
```

Which is registering the observer with the Fragment's `lifecycle` - **not** with the Fragment's **view** lifecycle (the one that is created in `onCreateView` and destroyed in `onDestroyView`). This means it will only get a single `onCreate` call when the Fragment's `onCreate` is called, not a call every time the fragment's view is created (e.g., `onCreateView` is called).

If you want your ActivityResultLauncher to be tied to the Fragment View lifecycle, then you need to use:

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)
```

That will ensure your `FileSelectorLifecycleObserver` is called every time the Fragment's view is created, which would be appropriate if you are creating a new Observer in every `onCreateView`.

Comment: Today I learned that fragment's views have lifecycles.  Not only elucidating, but a simple code change as well

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried directly registering the launcher as a fragment's private attribute instead of wrapping it in a dedicated `LifecycleObserver`?
This might avoid the need to deal with manually register/unregister and/or cleanup the `LifecycleObserver`, which might be the source of the bug here.

There is an example in the official documentation:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#launch